# Change layout view but lose data when return!

Tags: android

So I am writing an app for a golfer's scorecard. I setup a view for player1, initialise buttons and edit text and text view etc. I then can click to see next player and it does something similar for player 2. This all works fine - entering scores etc and seeing them on the screen. If, however, I try to go back to player1's view none of the data that was on the screen is there anymore. The textview, edit text boxes havent been "saved" if you like....why is this and how can I correct this?

Pseudo code below:

```
//Set up player 1 view
SetContentView(R.layout.player1);
//Initialise click listeners and buttons etc
initialiseClickListeners();
//setup EditText and Textviews
enterScore();

//if click on next player button then initialise buttons and boxes for player 2
SetContentView(R.layout.player2);
//Initialise click listeners and buttons etc
initialiseClickListeners();
//setup EditText and Textviews
enterScore();

//if click on next player button and there are no more players go back to player1
SetContentView(R.layout.player1);
//dont initialise buttons etc
```

WHY is the data that I had entered on view player1 not there anymore?

Answer (score 2):

setContentView loads new components from the layout file specified as parameter. Your old views (TextViews and EditText) from the initial load are not reused by using setContentView and therefor the data is not "there anymore". You could save the data and reapply it to the views instead of using setContentView.

Another solution would be to use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html), [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) or similar to make a nice  switch animation between the main views.

Comment: Do I have to re-initiliase all the buttons/edittext/textviews again? Surely once they are initialised they stay initialised? When I run the function that populates the player1 view with names etc nothing happens...

Comment: No, but you'll have to reuse the already initialized views instead of creating new ones.

Comment: I get this error 07-18 22:09:59.545: ERROR/jdwp(439): REQ: UNSUPPORTED (cmd=2/11 dataLen=8 id=0x00107c) when I try and write the name of the player back into player1 view?

Comment: Is it present in the current layout? When using setContentView, all current views are removed.

Comment: So how do I return to a view?

Comment: Save the main view, such as the root layout, and use it as parameter to setContentView instead of a resource id

Answer (score 0):

You should be retaining the data in some way meaning storing it and then once back on the player layout grab the data and populate the appropriate fields.